# Occipital 360 or Facebook Iphone app like Popup menu

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, menu, popup

Does anyone know how to create a popup menu like they have in Occipital 360 iPhone app? The menu slides up from the bottom giving a pleasing effect and looks great too.

The other example is Facebook's new Like and Comment floating menu which slides in from the right side (image below shows the old like/comment vs the new like/comment)

360 App : http://tinypic.com/r/34xglcg/7
Facebook: http://images.ientrymail.com/webpronews/article_pics/like-comment.gif

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely have to create a `UIView` subclass that draws the sort of view you want (and dismisses/removes itself when a touch is placed outside of itself).  I'm not sure about the specifics of the popup, since I don't see any pictures of the app in question with the 'share' button being pressed.  Without more details about how exactly this popup menu is supposed to function, though, I don't think I can say much.

Comment: THanks for your quick reply. I was adding images as you were replying. Just updated my post

Comment: Yeah, based on the images I'd say it's just a custom view that happens to be drawing a special background.  Probably nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a UIPopover view. Problem is UIPopOver is only supported on the iPad.

As a result you should implement your own version of the UIPopover or use some open source ports of UIPopover to iPhone like WePopover: https://github.com/PaulSolt/WEPopover

Thanks,

-David